# How to do multivariate local linear and kernel smoothing in matlab?

Tags: r, matlab, kernel, smoothing, loess

I have done local linear regression and kernel regression in R with this code:

```
llr =  loess(y~ x1+x2, span=0.1, degree=1) #local linear regression

lcr =  loess(y~ x1+x2,span=0.1, degree=0) #kernel regression
```

Is there a way to get the same results in Matlab?

With the function fit and the fittype lowess I come close to the results in R for local linear regression (`degree=1`). However, they are not equal.
The best command I found for kernel regression (`degree = 0`) with two independent variables is `ksrmv` but when putting in `x1` and `x2` I cannot set the bandwidth/span manually.

Thanks for your help!